# Issue with Java Regex \b

Tags: java, regex

I tried `\b` (This means the last character of a word) in the Java Regexp, but this doesn't work.

```
String input = "aaa aaa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a\b)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found this wiki word: " + matcher.group());
}
```

What in the problem?

Comment: Note: `\b` does not mean "last character of a word" but "boundary between word and non-word".

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, even with the regex corrected (`"a\\b"`, and see other comments about `\b`), your groups will always contain `a` only. So, what is it you want to do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java, `"\b"` is a back-space character (char `0x08`), which when used in a regex will match  a back-space literal.

You want the regex `a\b`, which in java is coded by escaping the back-slash, like this:

```
"a\\b"
```

btw, you are only partially correct about the meaning of regex `\b` - it actually means "word boundary" (either the start or end of a word).

Comment: *And* it might fail on non-ASCII words (unless you're using JDK 7) where `\b` matches in unexpected places (visualized by `|`: `Ü|bertr|ä|ger|`).

Answer (score 5):

Literal backslashes in Java strings need escaping, so the regex `\b` becomes `"\\b"` as a Java string.

Comment: Huh... what? Regex = regular expression.

Comment: Both `\\` and `\b` are escape sequence (character) in Java.

Comment: I'm just indicating that the **term** you're using is *incorrect*.

Comment: I'm telling nowhere \b is regex. Stop the useless comments.

Comment: "Regex in Java need double escaping: `\\b`" - what's that?

Comment: Huh? Where's \b there? I'm not answering further in this useless discussion.