# Match word followed by space and N number of digits

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to match a word followed by one space or tab character and 5 number digits. For example

```
some noise text off 12345 some noise text again.
```

Another example would be :

```
Some noise text off 12345.
```

The regex should match "off 12345".
Number may be followed by punctuation marks.
The pattern should match the word "off" and not any other word behind the number.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this

```
off\s\d{5}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5bvAh/1)**

Comment: thanks for your help Federico. It doesn't match "test off 12345 test." <-- this string...

Comment: @Davita, it does match, check the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/M5bvAh/3). However, if you want to match lines containing that pattern, then you can use `.*off\s\d{5}.*`

Comment: Sorry Federico, you are right, it's working, it was my mistake in the code. One problem I have now is that it matches first five part of six character number. For example, it matches 123456 from 1 to 5. Is it possible to make it the way so it will not match numbers with length higher than 5 characters? Thanks

Comment: @Davita, yes, you can use word boundary character, like this `\boff\s\d{5}\b` **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5bvAh/5)**. This allows you to not match things like `oooff 1234567` and will look for `off 12345`

Answer (score 2):

To be more generic, you can use

```
\b\w+\s\d{5}\b
```

Here `\b` matches the boundaries. If you do not use it, you may incorrectly match something like

```
123off 12345
off 1234567
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it. Problem is that I'm looking for a regex that will match 5 decimal digits exactly, not more not less. now it matches even more than 5 numbers in lenght.

Comment: I tested your examples on regex101. There seems no problem. Which of you case does it not work?

Comment: I'm testing on java, I guess implementations differ from platform to platform? For example, it doesn't match "test off 12345 test.".

Comment: This example also works on my side. There are two possible reasons. 1. You have more than one spaces, so you need `\s+`. 2. You did not escape the backslash in `\b`, and it instead matches a backspace character. In Java, the regex string should be `"\\b\\w+\\s\\d{5}\\b"`. This post may be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777982/issue-with-java-regex-b