# How to use string.replaceAll to change everything after a certain word

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string: `http://localhost:somePort/abc/soap/1.0`

I want the string to just look like this: `http://localhost:somePort/abc`.

I want to use string.replaceAll but can't seem to get the regex right.  My code looks like this: `someString.replaceAll(".*\\babc\\b.*", "abc");`
I'm wondering what I'm missing?  I don't want to split the string or use .replaceFirst, as many solutions suggest.

Comment: You might find it easier to do this without regular expressions just using `.substring`.

Comment: In this case I just want to use replaceAll and a regex pattern.  I'm trying to be consistent with other code in the class, even if it is flawed.

Comment: First, \\b is a back-space character: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777998/239613 I'd recommend using https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html to test your expression, you can test the replace all. Second, you're removing the first part, you should use a group to capture everything at the beginning: someString.replaceAll("(.*)\\/abc\\/.*", "$1/abc"); should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to make more sense to use `substring`, but if you must use `replaceAll`, here's a way to do it.

You want to replace `/abc` and everything after it with just `/abc`.

```
string = string.replaceAll("/abc.*", "/abc")
```

If you want to be more discriminating you can include a word boundary after `abc`, giving you

```
string = string.replaceAll("/abc\\b.*", "/abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for explanation on the given regex, why it wont work:

`\b` `\b` - word boundaries are not required here and also as `.*` is added in the beginning it matches the whole string and when you try to replace it with "abc" it will replace the entire match with "abc". Hence you get the wrong answer. Instead, only try to match what is required and then whatever is matched that will be replaced with "abc" string.

```
someString.replaceAll("/abc.*", "/abc");

/abc.* - Looks specifically for /abc followed by 0 or more characters
/abc - Replaces the above match with /abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `replaceFirst` since after first match you are removing all after

```
text=  text.replaceFirst("/abc.*", "/abc");
```

Or

You can use `indexOf` to get the index of certain word and then get substring.

```
String findWord = "abc";
text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(findWord) + findWord.length());
```